# Live Connect authentication status always "Unknown"

Tags: authentication, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-sdk

I'm facing some problem when authenticating in my WP8 app via Live SDK.

I have added a `SignInButton` to my app:

```xaml
<live:SignInButton x:Name="btnSignIn" 
    Scopes="wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update wl.signin wl.offline_access"
    ClientId="MY_CLIENT_ID" 
    SessionChanged="btnSignIn_SessionChanged" 
    TextType="Login" />
```

In the code-behind I have the following:

```cs
private async void btnSignIn_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    App.LiveSession = e.Session;
    if (e.Status == Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
        App.LiveClient = new Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectClient(e.Session);                               
    }
}
```

When I tap the SignIn button, I show the screen where I enter my credentials, and give permissions to the app. Everything fine until there.

The problem is that after that, `btnSignIn_SessionChanged` is fired, as expectyed, but I always get `Unknown` in `e.Stautus` property.

If I tap the SignIn button again, I'm not asked for credentials, but yes for permission. After accepting, `e.Status` keeps returning `Unknown`, when it should be `Connected`.

In http://dev.live.com I have my app configured as mobile client. The app used to work in the past, and I'm not able to guess where can be the problem.

Any clue?

Comment: Hi am facing a very similar issue . My questionis here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258248/after-first-scuccessful-login-logout-windows-live-sign-in-button-is-not-workin . Have you got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also occur if you are using a proxy server. Using "Automaticaly detect settings" in LAN settings fixed this issue for me.