# After first scuccessful login & logout windows live sign in button is not working on windows phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-sdk

Am creating an application which used Windows Phone Live Account & I referred [Windows Live Sdk sample  code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx) for doing that.

xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <my:SignInButton Name="btnSignin" ClientId="CLIENT_ID" Scopes="wl.signin wl.basic" Branding="Windows" TextType="SignIn" SessionChanged="btnSignin_SessionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />       
 </Grid>
```

Here is the logout code

```
    public void LogOut()
    {
        var authClient = new LiveAuthClient(ClientId);
        authClient.Logout();
    }
```

But after my first successful login & logout, i could not login to the live account means `Sign In` button is not working even it is not disabled at all.
 And Every time am getting a `LiveConnectSessionStatus.Unknown` state on `SessionChanged` event when i navigated to the login page. What will be the reason for this? Do i need to do anything more in the logout operation? Please confirm.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have different buton or option to Logout than using SignIn button?

Comment: @Romasz no , no need of it. But i just wants to avoid the issue

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have to do is:

```
    private LiveConnectClient client;

    private async void btnSignin_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);               
        }
        else
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
        }
    }
```

You don't have to program your own Logout - after you signin, the buton changes itself to logout. After SignIn and session changed you have Client - with what you can do what you need.

Comment: I tried in the same way you said but facing the same issue after first login & logout.

Comment: oh.!! I understood the reason now. There is a timer running for showing the memory consumption details on the screen in DEBUG mode. In RELEASE mode now i checked & no problem found. I just commented the timer initialisation & it just fine. Don't know why it happens?

Comment: I think it's not that. If you give wl.signin then when user sucessfully logged for the first time, he doesn't have to logout (the App remembers login and password). When you don't logout, after you navigate for second time and subscribe sessionchanged then it will be fired with connected. Check this - is it working?

Comment: Yea , that was correct in the case of not logged out. But in case of logged out am getting the Unknown state . And do you know how to logout from live account by another button click ?

Comment: When you logout (in my App) you get sessionchanged with Unknown (you logged out). After you logout, the App forgets user login and password (there can be many users on one phone). So when you navigate once again first you get unknown event in sessionchanged. But you can Sigin by clicking button, once again you are prompted for login and password.

Comment: The last case is not happening in my app. App is not showing the login  form again even the sign in button click able. But after i stopped or removed memory display timer it works fine for me. Don't know the reason behind this.

Comment: That's strange. Unfortunately I won't be able to help you with that issue (I also have no idea what can cause the problem).

Comment: Anyway very thanks @Romasz for your time. Now i just made it works with a tweak & have to find the reason later.

Answer (score 0):

as you in logout you are creating new session with

```
 public void LogOut()
    {
        var authClient = new LiveAuthClient(ClientId);
        authClient.Logout();
    }
```

you have to use session from which you logged in

and for that you will get logout automatically in session changed handler

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. How to attach session id with the auth client ?

Comment: @asitis are you using different button for logout?

Comment: oh.!! I understood the reason now. There is a timer running for showing the memory consumption details on the screen in DEBUG mode. In RELEASE mode now i checked & no problem found. I just commented the timer initialisation & it just fine. Don't know why it happens?

Comment: do you know how to logout from live account by another button click ?

Comment: @asitis you have to set the both buttons eventhandlers same

Comment: @asitis its session changed event which you are writitng in xaml will be same in both event

Comment: sorry , i didn't get you

Comment: @asitis use same session changed event for both buttons

Comment: But for a normal button ,SessionChanged event is not there. So how we can use this?